# Update value on adapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

I wonder if there is any way to update an information of a single item within a listview. Basically I press the button inside the adapter and it makes a new request, the request will set this returns the value of the adapter. It is a system of "like".

I do not want to call the asynchronous method that gets the list, it takes much again. The code to get all the items in the database is this:

```
 protected ArrayList<Feed> doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {

        page = params[0].page;
        mFilter = params[0].filter;
        backgroundItems = new ArrayList<Feed>();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FeedPost");
        ParseObject parseObject;
        try {
            responseList = query.find();
            for (int i = 0; i < responseList.size(); i++) {
                parseObject = responseList.get(i);
                backgroundItems.add(new Feed(parseObject.getObjectId(),
                        parseObject.getString("Title"),
                        parseObject.getString("Description"),
                        parseObject.getString("CompleteText"),
                        parseObject.getString("imageURL"),
                        parseObject.getString("Link_on_Site"),
                        parseObject.getNumber("like_count")));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            exceptionToBeThrown = e;
        }

        return backgroundItems;
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your adapter code or your task for updating the like count in the database, so I'm going to assume you're using an AsyncTask.  In the `getView` or `bindView` function is where you need to update it.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        //inflate layout and initialize holder
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    //get item at position
    MyItem item = getItem(position);
    if (item != null)
    {
        holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //update database and set new value
                    IncrementLikeCountTask task = new IncrementLikeCountTask()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onPostExecute(int newValue)
                        {
                            item.setLikeCount(newValue);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }.execute(position);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The  complete code is here: [http://pastebin.com/5NGgw948](http://pastebin.com/5NGgw948) it dont have mViewHolder.mLike.setOnClick...... because it don't have commited on github and I'm at work now.

Comment: That's fine, you can use my code and just fill in your variable names.  The important thing is to override your `AsyncTask` that updates the like count in your DB, and update the count on the UI in the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Strange, is not updating the value in the adapter when I click the button. 've Called notifyDataSetInvalidated and notifyDataSetChanged and nothing change. The value returned is usually just is not showing updated. The code is here: http://pastebin.com/qU5dz7Ue

Comment: If you're going to use `notifyDataSetChanged`, then I've modified my answer.  You need to change your data set before calling notifyDataSetChanged :)

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you're persisting a list of `Feed` objects in your adapter.

What you need to do is after communicating with the server modify the `like_count` field of the appropriate `Feed` object in your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

This will trigger a refresh of the `ListView` and render your list item with the updated value.